# How to add RegistryKey to all components in files generated by "heat" utility?

Tags: wix, heat

I create installation package from several *.wxs files where several of them are generated by **heat** utility and contains ComponentGroups.
Now I need to create installation package for per-user installation.
RegistryKey should be added to each component in case of creating of per-user installation package by Wix.
How to add RegistryKey to all components in files generated by **heat** utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no short way. You need to apply XSLT transformation to your heat generated file, and add the attributes.

In order to do so, you need to pass **-t yourTransformation.xslt** to **heat.exe**,

I blogged about something similiar in the past: http://chriseelmaa.com/xslt-wix-heat/ That's an example how you can add ServiceInstall element to specific **wix:Component**.

You'd probably want to take a look at this too, in order to see how to add attribute to wix:Component: [Copy node and add value to attribute with Xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355009/copy-node-and-add-value-to-attribute-with-xslt)

Comment: As I understand this transformation should add not only RegistryKey element but also RemoveFolder elements. Why there are so many manual steps in case of per-user installation?

Comment: WiX was never meant to be "simple" or "fast", the power comes from flexibility :-). If you want to make things simpler, feel free to contribute to WiX project(it's open source)

Comment: The content of _yourTransformation.xslt_ can be found in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455037/2372674 answer.